# Visual StudioでGitHubのリポジトリをクローンしたがソリューションが読み込まれてないみたいで実行できない

Tags: c, visual-studio

Visual StudioでGitHubのリポジトリをクローンしたが実行できません

`C:\Users\\{user\}\source\repos` にクローンしてるのですがソリューションがないみたいでデバッグをしようとしてもできずどうすればデバッグできるのでしょうか？

少ない情報かもしれず申し訳ないのですが、何かパッと思い浮かんだことを適当でも結構なので何が原因か思いついた方お願いします。

画面上には以下のメッセージが出力されています。

```
スキーマの読み込みでエラーが発生しました:
C:\Users\\{user\}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_eb4bba36\OpenFolder\CppProperties_schema.json
```

Comment: そのクローンして読み込もうとしているGitHubのリポジトリのURLを明記してください。プライベート等で公開できないのなら、同様の構成を持つと思われる公開されている他のリポジトリを探してそれで同じことをやってみるとか、そちらで出来るようなら違いの有無や内容を調べてみるとかしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif
ちょっと上げられなさそうです。すみません。c_cpp_properties.jsonとソリューションが関連していそうなのでそれをどうしようかというところです。

Comment: 他の方法で目的を遂げようと思うので、この方法はあきらめます。お答えくださった方、あと質問を修正してくださった方、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 一瞬だけ表示されていたリポジトリのCソースは`unistd.h`をインクルードしていて、他にshellスクリプトもあったので、Unix用だったと思われます。その場合、Visual Studioでソース修正やビルドくらいまでは出来ても、デバッグにはUnixOSとのリモート接続が必要になるでしょう。[Visual Studio で Linux MSBuild C++ プロジェクトを作成する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/linux/create-a-new-linux-project?view=msvc-170), [Linux MSBuild プロジェクトのデプロイ、実行、デバッグ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/linux/deploy-run-and-debug-your-linux-project?view=msvc-170) あるいはWindows上ではVisual StudioではなくMinGW,CygWin等の環境ならば出来るかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif お答えありがとうございます。永続的に目に入ることは避けたかったので一瞬表示されていたのを見ていただいていて助かりました。ソースの方もありがとうございます。なかなかビルド、デバッグ大変そうな印象を受けました。少々時間がかかりそうなので、現在時間に多少追われておりましてそれが終わったら試そうと思います。今はポインタとメモリの値の関連を目視でvisual studioのデバッグの機能を使い追っていきたかったので、githubからクローンしてきてそのままデバッグしようと思ったらいろいろ設定必要みたいなので、ソリューションを作成してコードをコピペして対応しようと思います。いずれにせよお答えいただきありがとうございます。